# Ubuntu 20.04, Killer E3100/AX1650i working on MSI GS75 10SGS

Tags: networking, 20.04

I just got my brand new MSI GS75, with 10-gen intel platform.

Installed Ubuntu 20.04, since I am a developer :-P.

Unfortunately the NIC does not work at all, wifi works, but is far from how fast it is
on my old GS73.

And to me it looks like Linux does not recognize the hardware, Windows reports
Killer/Atheros AX1650i for Wifi, and Killer/Atheros E3100 for wired.

But linux reports:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 00
       serial: 54:8d:5a:6f:d2:09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.1.47 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:ad71c000-ad71ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:d8:61:e4:86:05
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=0.0.1-k latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 memory:ad200000-ad2fffff memory:ad300000-ad303fff
```

To me it looks like it detects the wrong hardware and then installs the wrong drivers.

How can I get it to recognize the hardware? Report a bug to Ubuntu?

Comment: If you do think this is a bug: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem upgrading the Kernel version of Ubuntu to the 5.9.10.

Following this tutorial you can upgrade the Kernel manually easily:
https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

Remember that if you want to use the BIOS Secure Boot on the new Kernel you have to sign the Kernel:
https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html

Otherwise you have to disable the Secure Boot or the Kernel will not start.