# 20.04 killer e3100 NIC will not enable

Tags: networking, kernel, ethernet

I have recently purchased a high-spec clean machine, and installed 20.04 on it. I find that the Intel Killer E3100 card does not seem to be enable-able. The card itself has a wireless interface as well as Ethernet. It's supposed to be *very fast*. I get very slow wireless speed (presumably from a wifi adapter elsewhere in my system, as you'll see below) and *no* Wired Ethernet connection at all via the plug.

0. I checked with Intel, who promise me (and advertise the fact) that the card is compatible with Linux as well as windows, but Intel only supply the windows driver. They say support is built into the Linux kernel, and it is Linux's job to support. Sure enough their documentation shows a file I find in my own kernel, so I know it's there.
1. I have looked at the advice of one user, who mentioned the kernel being at least v8. Mine looks like v11:

```
$ sudo uname -r
5.11.0-34-generic
```

2. I have followed the advices I have seen here around the presence or content or location of the file named 10-globally-managed-devices.conf and restarting the networking service. Sadly no success.
3. My lshw shows up like this, and you can see my device reporting "DISABLED":

```
    $ sudo lshw -C network
      *-network DISABLED        
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: Intel Corporation
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:3f:00.0
           logical name: enp63s0
           version: 03
           serial: 38:14:28:35:43:a6
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:18 memory:b8200000-b82fffff memory:b8300000-b8303fff
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:40:00.0
           logical name: wlp64s0
           version: 1a
           serial: e0:2b:e9:d5:1b:dc
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.11.0-34-generic firmware=59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode ip=192.168.1.21 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:19 memory:b8400000-b8403fff
      *-network DISABLED
           description: Ethernet interface
           physical id: 3
           logical name: virbr0-nic
           serial: 52:54:00:6e:4a:4b
           size: 10Mbit/s
           capabilities: ethernet physical
           configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Am I just not turning it on properly? How should I do that?

Thanks in Advance ;-)

Comment: I'm a bit angry about Intel saying that it's Linux's job lol

Comment: I edited your post: ► create code fences with backticks ` or tildes ~

Comment: DISABLED usually means exactly that, disabled. Please check UEFI settings before anything else.

Answer (score -1):

Your WLAN speed is slow because you don't have a good driver (also happens for some Apple devices)

And I think there isn't any driver for that ethernet card... Or not installed at least. I think this is a duplicate of [Ubuntu 20.04, Killer E3100/AX1650i working on MSI GS75 10SGS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266180/ubuntu-20-04-killer-e3100-ax1650i-working-on-msi-gs75-10sgs)

But I am not sure. Sometimes Linux has basically just bad driver support which is sad

Comment: I looked at the issue you mention, and sadly it appeared to have been corrected by upgrading the kernel version to 5.9, but I am already at 5.11. Thanks for the edit to the code fences too, I was wondering how to do that.

Comment: Do it with ``` code ```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I hope you saw ther reply from ChaganAuto - make sure you also check that